# Django runserver, and s3boto backend

Tags: python, css, django, heroku, django-storage

Django's "manage.py runserver" has the wonderful ability to magically gather altered CSS, JS, and image files as it's running. This makes the save changes-reload cycle incredibly fast when doing front-end development (css especially). It's wonderful.

However, we've moved to Heroku recently, and installed django-storages with s3boto to handle static files. It works wonderfully too. However, "manage.py runserver" is no longer automatically showing us updated files. We have to run "manage.py collectstatic" to do so -- that works, but it adds an extra step, and slows down development while we wait for the collectstatic step to upload files to S3.

Is there any way to get the old behavior of runserver back, while keeping django-storages?

Comment: Why you develop on the heroku server and not your localhost?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But I have to run collectstatic to get "./manage.py runserver" to see the changed assets, even though I'm running locally. That's the problem I want to solve.

Comment: The way I solved this, was in settings.py... 'if not DEBUG:  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="..." STATICFILES_STORAGE = "s3boto3"...'